# Deleted Files causing Errors - Swift

Tags: swift

I had added some Objective-c bridging files for swift.
I deleted files both from the Xcode project folder and from the project itself.
When I compile it I receive the same error:

```
error reading '/Users/andrea/Desktop/MyProject/MyProject/Extensions/MyProject-Bridging-Header.h'
```

followed by

```
failed to emit precompiled header '/Users/andrea/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-cztnyjlmuzwtsggnyukvtrzzmhxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/MyProject-Bridging-Header-swift_3TZH4EISH2VD6-clang_NABFVTKQGFI2.pch' for bridging header '/Users/andrea/Desktop/Bound/Bound/Extensions/MyProject-Bridging-Header.h'
```

even if that file is already deleted.

I tried to clean build and restart the application but the error persists.
I also tried to delete derived data but the error doesn't change

Comment: did you try delete derived data ? Also I think you use Swift and Objective C class at the same time. Are you sure your codes true ? Which file did you delete ? After deleted it started ? Ohh I feel like myself Sherlock Holmes : pls more explanation

Comment: as said, did you delete the derived data and clean the cache: in Xcode -> Product > Clean Build Folder

Comment: @sekoyaz edited the question to be more specific, trying to be your Watson

Comment: @benjiii I tried both and none worked, I assume this happens because the file I deleted were not swift files but instead conversion files in Obj-c

Comment: then add your swift classes to bridge file that is what is supposed to be

Comment: I added a new File with the name of the file it was missing and now it works fine; but how can I actually delete it without causing any errors?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution:

You need to go in your Target "Build Settings" and delete the Objective-C Bridging Header